# hashCode collisions are putting two different words in same position

Tags: java, eclipse, hashtable

I am supposed to implement an interface with a hash table. Problem is that I'm getting the wrong output and it's due to collision (from what I understand). I haven't been writing this code completely solo, I've been getting help. I'm not a master at Java, very early in my course so this is all very hard for me so please be patient.

Here is my code so far:

**runStringDictionary.java**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class runStringDictionary {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (args.length == 0 || args.length > 1) {
            System.out.println("Syntax to run the program: java runStringDictionary <inputFile>");
        }
        if (args.length == 1) {
            try {

                Dictionary myDictionary = new Dictionary(); //Initialize a Dictionary to store input words
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0])); //Read the text file input
                String line;

                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {//Read each line
                    String[] strArray = line.split(" "); //Separate each word in the line and store in another Array
                    for (int i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++) { //Loop over the Array
                        if (myDictionary.contains(strArray[i])) { //Check if word exists in the dictionary
                            myDictionary.remove(strArray[i]); //if it does remove it
                        } else {
                            myDictionary.add(strArray[i]); //if it doesn't then add it
                        }
                    }
                }//while loop ends

                //print the contents of myDictionary
                for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
                    if (myDictionary.table[i] != null) {
                        System.out.println(myDictionary.table[i]);
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error found : " + e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**StringDictionary.java**

```
public interface StringDictionary {

    public boolean add(String s);

    public boolean remove(String s);

    public boolean contains(String s);
}
```

**Dictionary.java**

```
public class Dictionary implements StringDictionary {
    private int tableSize = 25;
    Object[] table;

    // constructor
    Dictionary() {
        this.table = new Object[this.tableSize];
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(String s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int hashCode = s.hashCode() % this.tableSize;
        if (!this.contains(s)) {
            this.table[hashCode] = s;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(String s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int hashCode = s.hashCode() % this.tableSize;
        if (this.contains(s)) {
            this.table[hashCode] = null;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(String s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int hashCode = s.hashCode() % this.tableSize;
        if (table[hashCode] != null) {
            if (table[hashCode].equals(s))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: The `hashCode` may be the same, but you should also check if the entry is the same. This can be achieved by using `equals`.

Answer (score 1):

Hash code collisions are normal in hash tables, you would have to have a perfect hash function in order to avoid them. There are [multiple strategies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), that you can implement in order to deal with collisions, but basically, either you move items around in the list, placing them to different buckets, or you allow each bucket to store multiple values, such as through ArrayList.

Deciding, which value to retrieve from the table, if multiple values share the same hash code brings additional cost in terms of lookup time, therefore a good hash function will minimise the number of collisions as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Hashcode collisions are expected and normal; the hashcode is used to narrow down the pool of potential matches and those potential matches must then be checked for canonical equality.

Comment: Alright so it's fine that my output is incorrect? I'm supposed to turn this in as an assignment.. Obviously you are not my professor but seeing as this is the introduction course to programming is it safe to assume that this is enough? Or do I need to perfect it?

Answer (score 1):

This `int hashCode = s.hashCode() % this.tableSize;` says that your Dictionary can contain only 25 elements. For any string you'll get a hashCode from 0 to 24.

You need to keep an array of lists. Each list contains string with the same hasCode.

Answer (score 0):

```
int hashCode = s.hashCode() % this.tableSize; will
```

You are bound to get collisions here. Valid indices into `table` run from `0` to `this.tableSize - 1`, which in your case is `24`.

Hashcode collisions are *expected* and are a normal occurrence. Having the same hash code doesn't mean that the elements are equal; it just means that they hash to the same value. You have to look at the contents to be sure.

The aim in a structure like this is usually to create a hash function that *reduces* the probability of collisions. You currently have a very simple hashing function that is simply the modulus of the hash code with the size of your table, and so you have a `1 / tableSize` chance of a collision (someone please correct me here if I am wrong).